# Hardfor and Bitcoin wallet balances

Tags: wallet, balance

hardfork is coming. Is there any risk to use an application? I will have the same bitcoin balance after  fork's procedures are completed?

Comment: Can you clarify the meaning of "use an application"? Do you mean using a bitcoin wallet?

Answer (score 1):

The balance of your Bitcoin holdings won't change. You will be able to use the same wallet on both chains, but note that both chains don't have replay protection, so transacting on either chain can lead to hijacked transactions in the other.

If you upgrade to the latest version of your applications, you should not encounter any problems with the hardfork, since the original chain will just continue. You might not be able to access your funds on the other chain though.